# Replace strings like new Date(1358467200000) with a valid date

Tags: php, regex, json

I'm making a jsonp version of a json file using PHP, and I've noticed the author put stuff like this instead of valid dates in the json file:

```
"StartPublish" : new Date(1356652800000)
```

I need to replace all occurrences of `new Date(timestamp)` with that timestamp represented as a valid date format like `Fri Dec 28 2012 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)` using PHP.

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: It should be easier with JS, which can natively `eval`uate object literals and `new Date` expressions. Any JSON parser will reject that syntax.

Comment: You really want timezone-dependent date strings instead? Why not just convert to integer?

Comment: you could, of course, just output the timestamp. JS will happily take that (as demonstrated by the code you've already got)

Comment: Timestamps are regular dates. What you want is a representation if a date. Why not let JS do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't now about your JSON contents. Try `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$jsonPost = preg_replace_callback('/:\s*new\s+Date\(([0-9]+)\)/', function($match) {
    return ': "'. date('r', $match[1] / 1000). '"';
}, $jsonPre);
```

The date can be formatted according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

> I'm making a jsonp version of a json file

Then you don't have any problems. The format you currently have might not be valid JSON, but wrapping it in the callback function will create a valid JSONP script with object literals and `Date` invocations - no conversion needed. Just

```
echo $_GET["callback"] . "($nearlyJSON);";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo  date("d/m/Y h:i:s",strtotime($strtime));
```